# C1 CMS friendly media urls?

Tags: c#, c1-cms

Media urls use uuids which is great for internal linking, but not great for SEO. My client has PDFs that they want to appear in the sitemap and in searches with seo-friendly urls. I've been able to do this with data objects by adding a url field and searching based on that when retrieving data objects, but I'm not good enough at c1 or c# to know if I can add a url field to a media item.

I looked for an add-on that could do this and also contacted the company for support.

Best I could come up with was adding the PDFs outside the media area or adding redirects from seo-friendly urls to internal media uuids. Neither of these is ideal.

Comment: why can't your url look like this `https://www.example.com/viewsomething.aspx?key=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&description=an amazing product for your desk`  Then you just ignore the description part application and let the search index the words

Comment: What exactly does "C1" stand for? The file transfer protocoll also known as Punter? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punter_(protocol)

Comment: C1 is a CMS: https://c1.orckestra.com/

Comment: How come that the current urls which consists of both path and filename with extension isn't good enough?